# Is it possible to get for deleted profile?

Tags: custom-profile

How can I retrieve deleted profile. I need to know the solution. why won't I get deleted profile. Please can any one suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike records, profiles are part of the metadata, therefore they are not stored in the Recycle Bin.You may be able to recover via customer support. I'm not certain of that.

Tip: Every so often, use the Metadata API to download your org's source and related metadata. Reference and tutorial links:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index.htm